# Using input from form as a variable to retrieve data from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Looks like it's my day. If it makes you feel better, you're probably helping me keep my job (as a GRAPHIC designer, but people seem to forget programming is not the same...).

So, my previous question was answered successfully and things work now. However, I'd like to be able to set the variable SOMETHING in this form with a text input field (if I enter the name of the product, it displays all it's data).

What I got now, with the variable hardcoded:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbname = 'test';
$dbpass = '';
$dbcharset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=$dbcharset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $opt);

$sql = 'SELECT Name, id, Variant, dim1 FROM products WHERE Name=?';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(["SOMETHING"]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP); 
?>


<?php 

foreach($data as $name => $products) {

        echo $name .'<br>';

foreach($products as $row) {
        echo $row['Variant'] .'<br>';
}


}


?>
```

This file is called testdb.php, I also have test.php where I set up the input box:

```
<html>
<body>

<form name='form' method='post' action="testdb.php">

Name: <input type="text" name="SOMETHING" id="SOMETHING"><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to define in testdb.php it like:

```
$something = $_POST['SOMETHING'];
```

with the other variables but it only gives me an empty result. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Change `$stmt->execute(["SOMETHING"]);`  TO `$stmt->execute($_POST["SOMETHING"]);`

Comment: `$stmt->execute(["SOMETHING"]);` you execute the string, not the content from that form. You'll have to get it from the POST-array: `$stmt->execute($_POST['SOMETHING']);` should do the trick.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use the `$_POST['SOMETHING']` variable, you can put it in your request execution:

```
$stmt->execute([$_POST['SOMETHING']]);
```

Don't forget to check your POST variable before: never trust the user's input! ;)

EDIT: As @Qirel says, verification of the variable is not necessary using prepared statement

Comment: OP is using prepared statements, so he isn't trusting his user-input ;-)

Comment: Just playing with the code right now, it doesn't return any errors, but also no data... The resulting page is completely empty, unless I manually enter the specific variable to execute... Any ideas? :)

Comment: Check if you correctly send the POST varaible to the server (with an `echo` of `$['SOMETHING']`).